# module export - Getting property 'default' of undefined in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, eslint, es6-modules

Facing problem with **importing and exporting files**. This was working with **react-native 0.51.0**

But not in **react-native: 0.56**

```
"babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
```

Is it a problem with module.exports and export default or with babel version?

Getting error saying that

> Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
>   Object.get [as API]

**repolib/index.js**

```
import * as components from './components';
import * as utils from './utils';

var Utils = {
  Logger: utils.Logger,
  Toast: utils.Toast
}

var Components = {
  Button: components.Button
}

module.exports = {
  Utils,
  Components,
}
```

**Utils/Toast.js**

```
var Toast = require('../repolib').Utils.Toast;
export default {
  ...(Toast)
}
```

**API/loginAPI.js**

```
import Toast from '../Utils/Toast';
export default {
  login: () => {...}
}
```

**API/index.js**

```
import loginAPI from './loginAPI';
export default {
  loginAPI
}
```

**common/index.js**

```
export { default as API } from '../API';
```

[image]

Comment: Which babel version is in use?

Comment: @Mukeyii Updated

Comment: It looks like a babel issue to me. I had an issue like this with babel 7.0.0-beta.53 (which is required by babel-preset-react-native). Which version is installed in package-lock.json?

@Edit: This issue is fixed in my current version (...beta.47)

Comment: in package.json 
babel-preset-react-native: 5.0.2
babel-eslint: 7.2.3

Comment: "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.47". I am also using the same version. Should I need to check something else?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error? The message on its own is useless.

Comment: @loganfsmyth updated the stack trace error